# How to validate AGGREGATE with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel-formula, apache-poi

I'm trying to feed an Excel spreadsheet with a Java program, using Apache POI (XSSF).
After having injected the data, I'm trying to validate the formulas, already coded in the spreadsheet.

The issue is that this validation (sheet-global or cell by cell) fails when it comes to the "AGGREGATE" function.

> Error evaluating cell 'MS Roadmap'!WC1
>
> Caused by:
> org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedFunctionException:
> _xlfn.AGGREGATE

Where the WC1's formula is:

```
=AGREGAT(9;2;WD1:WG1) (here in French ;-))
```

I've tried as well to not validate the formulas, but, when opening the file, even the F9 key doesn't work to force updating the formulas ... so this is not an option.

Any ideas on how to solve this ?

O.

Comment: The  exception `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedFunctionException` means that the function is not implemented by `apache poi`. That's why evaluating using `apache poi` is not possible until you implement the function. But using `wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);`, as told in [Recalculation of Formulas](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html#recalculation), delegates re-calculation to Excel. The application will perform a full recalculation when the workbook is opened.

Comment: _I'm trying to validate the formulas_ Do you mean that you are trying to **evaluate** the formulas? Refer to this Web page: https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html

Comment: Axel Richter was right: forcing the validation at opening works well. Thanks Axel.